# Pandas Boolean Mask for Columns that Contain String

Tags: python, pandas, string, boolean, mask

Python newbie here, trying to create a boolean mask for subsetting dataset. I would appreciate any guidance on how to make this mask work and what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

My df looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A-dog', "B-dog","C-cat" , "E-snake", "F-hamser"],
                  'B': ['F-dog', "B-parrot","C-snake" , "E-cat", "F-bird"],
                  'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'D': [22,23,24,25,26],
                  'E': ['A-snake', "B-dog","C-snake" , "E-snake", "F-snake"],
                  'Flag': [0,0,0,0,0]})


df
```

I want to evaluate columns A, B & E and replace cells that end with "dog" & "cat" with "" and change the 'Flag' column to 1 on rows in which I made replacements.

I want to create a boolean mask so that I can replace the string and change the 'Flag ' to 1 but my mask is not working.

This is what I have tried:

```
cols=['A','B','E']
mask=df[cols].apply(lambda x: 'dog'  or 'cat' in x[-3:])
# x[-3:] to select the last three characters of the string.
# If the mask were working, I would change the flag variable in this way
df.loc(mask.any(axis=1),'Flag')=1
```

My resulting df would look like this:

```
res= pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A-', "B-","C-" , "E-snake", "F-hamser"],
                  'B': ['F-', "B-parrot","C-snake" , "E-", "F-bird"],
                  'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'D': [22,23,24,25,26],
                  'E': ['A-snake', "B-","C-snake" , "E-snake", "F-snake"],
                  'Flag': [1,1,1,1,0]})


res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

Create a series for Flag using the str.endswith function.

```
s = df.select_dtypes('object').apply(lambda x: x.str.endswith(('dog', 'cat'))).any(axis=1).astype('int')
```

`s`

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int32
```

then use replace with regex & change Flag column

```
df.replace({'dog$':'', 'cat$':''}, regex=True).assign(Flag=s)
```

output:

```
    A           B           C   D   E       Flag
0   A-          F-          1   22  A-snake 1
1   B-          B-parrot    2   23  B-      1
2   C-          C-snake     3   24  C-snake 1
3   E-snake     E-          4   25  E-snake 1
4   F-hamser    F-bird      5   26  F-snake 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the mask with `.str.endswith` (this function accepts tuple of values too):

```py
cols = ["A", "B", "E"]
mask = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.endswith(("dog", "cat")))

df["Flag"] = mask.any(axis=1).astype(int)
df[mask] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: x.str[:-3] if x.notna().any() else x)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          A         B  C   D        E  Flag
0        A-        F-  1  22  A-snake     1
1        B-  B-parrot  2  23       B-     1
2        C-   C-snake  3  24  C-snake     1
3   E-snake        E-  4  25  E-snake     1
4  F-hamser    F-bird  5  26  F-snake     0
```